# ggplot - how to avoid histogram half bins and oversmoothed KDE?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a distribution as shown below.

First, how do I avoid half bins? It seems even with setting the binwidth to a manual value I still get them.

Secondly, can I use `geom_density` to smoothe over exponential-like distributions AND gaussian-like distributions, in the same data set? I'm plotting several different distributions with `facet_wrap`, but the standard KDE only looks good 
for gaussian-like distributions without too much skew.

Edit: dput sample data:
https://pastebin.com/anezb1SZ

And the code

```
ggplot(data = Test, aes(x = Test,
                        y = ..density..)) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0,
                 col = "black") +
    geom_histogram(alpha = 0.7,
                   col = "black",
                   binwidth = 2e-9) +
    scale_fill_discrete() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                       breaks = c(0, 1.5e8, 3e8)) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1e-15,3.5e-8),
                    ylim = c(0,1.5e8)) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You will need to post the code you used as a starting point...

Comment: Sorry about that. Added now.